# Mixed Models: How to derive Henderson's mixed-model equations?

Tags: mixed-model, matrix, linear-algebra

In the context of best linear unbiased predictors (BLUP), Henderson specified the mixed-model equations (see Henderson (1950): Estimation of Genetic Parameters. Annals of Mathematical Statistics, 21, 309-310). Let us assume the following mixed effects model:

$y = X\beta+Zu+e$

where $y$ is a vector of n observable random variables, $\beta$ is a vector of $p$ fixed effects, $X$ and $Z$ are known matrices, and $u$ and $e$ re vectors of $q$ and $n$ random effects such that $E(u) = 0$ and $E(e) = 0$ and

$    Var \begin{bmatrix}
    u \\
    e \\
    \end{bmatrix} =     
\begin{bmatrix}
    G & 0 \\
    0 & R \\
    \end{bmatrix}\sigma^2$

where $G$ and $R$ are known positive definite matrices and $\sigma^2$ is a positive constant.

According to Henderson (1950), the BLUP estimates of $\hat {\beta}$ of $\beta$ and $\hat {u}$ of $u$ are defined as solutions to the following system of equation:

$X'R^{-1}X\hat {\beta}+X'R^{-1}Z\hat {u} = X'R^{-1}y$

$Z'R^{-1}X\hat {\beta}+(Z'R^{-1}Z + G^{-1})\hat {u} = Z'R^{-1}y$

(Also see: Robinson (1991): That BLUP is a good thing: the estimation of random effects (with discussion). Statistical Science, 6:15–51).

I have not found any derivation of this solution but assume that he approached it as follows:

$(y - X\beta - Zu)'V^{-1}(y - X\beta - Zu)$

where $V = R + ZGZ'$. Hence the solutions should therefore be

$X'V^{-1}X\hat {\beta} + X'V^{-1}Z\hat {u} = X'V^{-1}y$

$Z'V^{-1}X\hat {\beta} + Z'V^{-1}Z\hat {u} = Z'V^{-1}y$.

We also know that $V^{-1} = R^{-1} - R^{-1}Z(G^{-1}+Z'R^{-1}Z)Z'R^{-1}$.

However, ho to proceed to arrive at the mixed-model equations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach is to form the log-likelihood and differentiate this with respect to the random effects $\mathbf{u}$ and set this equal to zero, then repeat, but differentiate with respect to the fixed effects $\boldsymbol{\beta}$.

With the usual normality assumptions we have:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y|u} &\sim \mathcal{N}\mathbf{(X\beta + Zu, R)} \\
\mathbf{u} &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0, G})
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathbf{y}$ is the response vector, $\mathbf{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ are the random effects and fixed effects coefficient vectors $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ are model matrices for the fixed effects and random effects respectively.
The log-likelihood is then:

$$
-2\log L(\boldsymbol{\beta,}\mathbf{u}) = \log|\mathbf{R}|+(\mathbf{y - X\boldsymbol{\beta} - Zu})'\mathbf{R}^{-1}(\mathbf{y - X\boldsymbol{\beta} - Zu}) +\log|\mathbf{G}|+\mathbf{u'G^{-1}u}
$$
Differentiating with respect to the random and fixed effects:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \log L}{\partial \mathbf{u}} &= \mathbf{Z'R^{-1}}(\mathbf{y - X\boldsymbol{\beta} - Zu}) - \mathbf{G^{-1}u} \\
\frac{\partial \log L}{\partial \boldsymbol{\beta}} &= \mathbf{X'R^{-1}}(\mathbf{y - X\boldsymbol{\beta} - Zu})
\end{align*}
$$
After setting these both equal to zero, with some minor re-arranging, we obtain Henderson's mixed model equations:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Z'R^{-1}}\mathbf{y} &= \mathbf{Z'R^{-1}X\boldsymbol{\beta}} + \mathbf{u(Z'R^{-1}Z+G^{-1})} \\
\mathbf{X'R^{-1}}\mathbf{y} &= \mathbf{X'R^{-1}X\boldsymbol{\beta}} + \mathbf{X'R^{-1}Zu}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense. Just a follow-up question. Since we assume normality of both _u_ and _e_, we can form the log likelihood by using the joint density of _u_ and _e_. Within this joint density, we have a variance-covariance matrix with _G_ and _R_ on the diagonal. If we now assume a three-level model with _H_ being the variance-covariance matrix of the third-level random effect, then we would have _G_, _R_, and _H_ on the diagonal? Cheers

Comment: You are very welcome. Please post this follow-up as a new question, perhaps with a link to this question.

Comment: Done! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386474/what-is-the-joint-density-function-of-3level-mixed-effects-model

Comment: Should it not be $X'R^{-1}Zu$ on the last line? Similarly for the above?

Comment: @JDoe2 I don't think so, but I'm a bit rusty on this now. It seems to match [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/synbreed/versions/0.12-9/topics/MME)  doesn't it ?

Comment: @JDoe2 The final equations look right to me but there could be an error in the differentiation.

Comment: You have $uX'R^{-1}Z$. If $X$ has dimensions $(n \times p)$ and $Z$ has dimensions $(n \times q)$ then $u$ must have dimension $(q \times 1)$. But looking at $uX'R^{-1}Z$ the dimensions of the first matrix multiplication don't make sense then.

Comment: Right. $X'R^{-1}Zu$ actually does make sense !

Comment: I believe the same should be true for the line above as well... i.e. $(Z'R^{-1}Z+G^{-1})u$ rather than $u(Z'R^{-1}Z+G^{-1})$... I think

Comment: Looks like you are right again. Maybe you should just edit it :)

Comment: I'll chim in: I can verify the result. It's also the same as in McCulloch and Searle (eq 9.35).  They leave the derivation as an exercise.

Answer (score 4):

For a very simple derivation, without making any assumption on normality, see my paper

A. Neumaier and E. Groeneveld, [Restricted maximum likelihood estimation of covariances in sparse linear models](http://arnold-neumaier.at/ms/reml.pdf), Genet. Sel. Evol. 30 (1998), 3-26.

Essentially, the mixed model
$$y=X\beta+Zu+\epsilon,~~ Cov(u)=\sigma^2 G,~~ 
Cov(\epsilon)=\sigma^2 D,$$
where $u$ and $\epsilon $ have zero mean and wlog $G=LL^T$ and $D=MM^T$, is equivalent to the assertion that with $x=\pmatrix{\beta \cr u}$ and $P=\pmatrix{M & 0\cr 0 &L}$, $E=\pmatrix{I \cr 0}$, $A=\pmatrix{X & Z \cr 0 & I}$, the random vector $P^{-1}(Ey-Ax)$ has zero mean and covariance matrix $\sigma^2 I$. Thus the best linear unbiased predictor is given by the solution of the normal equations
for the overdetermined linear system $P^{-1}Ax=P^{-1}Ey$. This gives Henderson's mixed model equations.