Mathematical Prediction of Linear Mixed Models Random Intercept
Given data $\{(x_{i,j}, y_{i,j})\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, with $i = 1, \ldots, k$ classes and $j = 1, \ldots, n_i$. The linear mixed model is:
\begin{equation*}
y_{i,j} = a + b x_{i,j} + u_i + \epsilon_{i,j}
\end{equation*}
Here $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$ are unknown constats. $u_i$ and $\epsilon_{i,j}$'s are independent identically distributed normal random variables having $0$ mean and unknown variance $\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$ and $\sigma_{u}^2$. After we fit the model in whatever way by lmer, we will have an estimation of $a$, $b$,
$\sigma_{\epsilon}^2$ and $\sigma_{u}^2$.
Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, what is the MATHEMATICAL formula for its prediction? Posts like predict() Function for lmer Mixed Effects Models does not seem to give a clean answer.

If the data are perfectly balanced ($x_{ij}$ has the same set of values for each group) then I think there is a closed-form solution, otherwise I'm not sure there is ...

It is fine there is no closed form solution, I just would like to know how to obtain it mathematically such that, if I code it out, it would reproduce the results.

Perhaps the easiest place to start is Henderson's mixed model equations? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386109/mixed-models-how-to-derive-hendersons-mixed-model-equations

For a random intercepts model, the formula for the empirical Bayes estimate of the random effect is $$\hat{u}_i = \frac{\hat{\sigma}_u^2}{\hat{\sigma}_\epsilon^2 + n_i \hat{\sigma}_u^2} \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n_i}(y_{ij} - \hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} x_{ij}),$$ where $n_i$ is the number of measurements for group $i$, $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ are the estimated regression coefficients, and $\hat{\sigma}_u^2$ and $\hat{\sigma}_\epsilon^2$ the estimated variance components.
The following code illustrates how this is done using lme4:
library("lme4")
fm <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)

# data for a subject
data_i <- sleepstudy[sleepstudy$Subject == 308, ]
# outcome for the subject
y_i <- data_i$Reaction
# number of measurements
n_i <- length(y_i)
# fixed effects part for this subject
mu_i <- predict(fm, newdata = data_i, re.form = NA)
# variance components
vc <- VarCorr(fm)
# random intercepts variance
sigma2_u <- vc$Subject
# measurement error variance
sigma2 <- attr(vc, "sc")^2

# random effect estimate
sum(y_i - mu_i) * sigma2_u / (n_i * sigma2_u + sigma2)

# check that it works using the ranef() function
ranef(fm)$Subject[1L, ]

The corresponding prediction for the outcome $y_{ij}$ will then be $$\hat{y}_{ij} = \hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta}x_{ij} + \hat{u}_i.$$
And the calculation in R:
# prediction from the formula
alpha <- fixef(fm)[1L]
beta <- fixef(fm)[2L]
mu_i <- alpha + beta * data_i$Days
u <- sum(y_i - mu_i) * sigma2_u / (n_i * sigma2_u + sigma2)
mu_i + c(u)

# from lme4 using predict()
predict(fm, newdata = data_i)


This is excellent, exactly what I want. Thank you. Do you mind giving also a source about how this empirical Bayes is derived?

Below I will explain the idea behind a method used to predict the random intercept in a multilevel model. So my answer is about this underlying idea, and not about a fast way to calculate the predicted intercepts for all "schools", which was already explained in the answer by Dimitris Rizopoulos.
Let us start with a multiple linear regression model. Below, the estimates of the regression coefficients $b$ will be expressed in terms of covariances.
Consider the multiple linear regression of dependent $Y$ on $p$ independent variables, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_p$:
$$Y = b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + ... + b_pX_p + e\tag 1\label 1$$
Assume $Y$ and all independents $X$ have zero mean, hence, the regression equation has no intercept. Let $\Sigma_{XX}$ be the sample estimate of the $p\times p$ covariance matrix of the independents; let $\Sigma_{XY}$ be a $p$ length column vector containing the sample estimates of the covariances of the $p$ independents with $Y$. The OLS estimates of the regression coefficients $b$ in equation $\eqref 1$ are given by:
$$\hat{b}= \Sigma^{-1}_{XX}\Sigma_{XY},$$
where $\hat{b}$ is a $p$ length column vector containing the estimates of $b_1, b_2, ... , b_p$ etc.
Now we turn to the random intercept model:
$$y_{ij}= b_0 + b_1x_i + u_j + e_{ij}\tag 2\label 2$$
Once the fixed effects $\hat{b}_0$ and $\hat{b}_1$ of $b_0$ and $b_1$ in $\eqref 2$ are estimated, the "raw residuals" $r_{ij}=u_j + e_{ij}$ can be calculated with $r_{ij} = y_{ij} -\hat{b}_0-\hat{b}_1x_{ij}$. Suppose a "school" $j$ has three "pupils" $i$, then all three raw residuals of these pupils contain the same $u_j$ term! This suggests that we may be able to predict the value of the unknown $u_j$ by using the three raw residuals as predictors in a linear regression model. This leads to the following regression equation:
$$u_j = b_1r_{1j} + b_2r_{2j} + b_3r_{3j} + \textrm{error}\tag 3\label 3$$
This equation does not need an intercept, because the mean of the dependent $u_j$ and the means of the three independents $r$ are zero. To estimate the three $b$'s in $\eqref 3$  we need to have (an estimate of) the covariance matrix of the three predictors $r$ (which above was denoted by $\Sigma_{XX}$) and also the covariances of the dependent $u_j$ with the three raw residuals $r$ (called $\Sigma_{XY}$ above). All these covariances can be derived from the random effect estimates of our random effects model $\eqref 3$, namely the intercept variance $\sigma^2_u$ and the residual variance $\sigma^2_e$. The variance of each of the raw residuals $r$ is obviously $\sigma^2_u + \sigma^2_e$. The covariance of two raw residuals can easily be proven to be equal to $\sigma^2_u$. And finaly, the covariances of the $u_j$ and the three raw residuals $r$, which together form $\Sigma_{XY}$, are also equal to $\sigma^2_u$. This means that all covariances are "known" once model $\eqref 2$ has been estimated!
So, we estimate model $\eqref 2$, build the two covariance matrices $\Sigma_{XX}$ and $\Sigma_{XY}$, estimate the $\hat{b}$'s in $\eqref 3$, and then apply these $\hat{b}$ estimates to calculate or predict the $u_j$ values!
I did not figure out yet how this method relates to the one presented in Dimitris's fine answer (+1) but that is not too difficult I hope, and leave that up to you :-). My method comes from Harvey Goldstein's book Multilevel Statistical Models.
Here is an R script which follows the method described above.
    # Generate a data frame.
    y <- c(1,2,3, 6,4,6,8, 7,5,8,11,12)
    x <- c(1,3,4, 1,7,5,4, 7,6,9,6,8)
    school <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
    da <- data.frame(school,y,x)
    
    # Estimate the multilevel model.
    library(lme4)
    m1 <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|school), da)
    
    # Extract random effect variances of model m1.
    s2u  <- VarCorr(m1)$school[1] # intercept variance.
    s2e  <- attr(VarCorr(m1), "sc")^2 # residual variance.
    
    # Calculate the raw residuals.
    da$rawresid <- da$y - predict(m1, re.form= ~0)
    
    
    # Calculate the theoretical covariance matrix SXX of three raw residuals taken from the same school.
    # This matrix is NOT for one particual school but is assumed to hold for all schools with
    # three pupils. 
    SXX <- matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3, s2u)
    diag(SXX) <- s2u + s2e
    
    # Calculate covariances of raw residuals and u0j. 
    SXY <- rep(s2u, 3) 
    
    # Calculate the b coefficients.
    bees <- SXY %*% solve(SXX)
    
    # Calculate the predicted uj for school 1, which has three pupils.
    preduj <- bees %*% da$rawresid[school==1]
    preduj
    
    # Compare this with the random effect of school 1, as given by lmer: identical! 
    ranef(m1)


For labeling the equations, you can use \tag and for referencing them later, you can use \label, \eqref. I have made a few edits in that vein. Please check those.

Thanks User1865345 and Dimitris for the editing!
